# Read lines in one file and find all strings starting with 4-letter strings listed in another txt file

Tags: python, regex, find, substring, combinations

I have 2 txt files (a and b_).

file_a.txt contains a long list of 4-letter combinations (one combination per line):

```
aaaa
bcsg
aacd
gdee
aadw
hwer
etc.
```

file_b.txt contains a list of letter combinations of various length (some with spaces):

```
aaaibjkes
aaleoslk
abaaaalkjel
bcsgiweyoieotpwe
csseiolskj
gaelsi asdas
aaaloiersaaageehikjaaa
hwesdaaadf wiibhuehu
bcspwiopiejowih
gdeaes
aaailoiuwegoiglkjaaake
etc.
```

I am looking for a python script that would allow me to do the following:

1. read file_a.txt line by line
2. take each 4-letter combination (e.g. aaai)
3. read file_b.txt and find all the various-length letter combinations starting with the 4-letter combination (eg. **aaai**bjkes, **aaai**loiersaaageehikjaaa, **aaai**loiuwegoiglkjaaaike etc.)
4. print the results of each search in a separate txt file named with the 4-letter combination.

File aaai.txt:

```
aaaibjkes 
aaailoiersaaageehikjaaa
aaailoiuwegoiglkjaaake
etc.
```

File bcsi.txt:

```
bcspwiopiejowih
bcsiweyoieotpwe
etc.
```

I'm sorry I'm a newbie. Can someone point me in the right direction, please. So far I've got only:

```
#I presume I will have to use regex at some point
import re

file1 = open('file_a.txt', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('file_b.txt', 'r').readlines()

#Should I look into findall()?
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with combinations. When we talk about combinations, we talk about the different ways to form a string. Such as a combination of `a`, `b`, `c` of length 2 would look like `ab` `bc`, ca`

Comment: Thanks. Shall we call them "strings", then. All the entries in file_a.txt and file_b.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to open both files and run both files down line by line using `for` loops.

You can have two `for` loops, the first one reading `file_a.txt` as you will be reading through it only once. The second will read through `file_b.txt` and look for the string at the start.

To do so, you will have to use `.find()` to search for the string. Since it is at the start, the value should be `0`.

```
file_a = open("file_a.txt", "r")
file_b = open("file_b.txt", "r")

for a_line in file_a:
    # This result value will be written into your new file
    result = ""
    # This is what we will search with
    search_val = a_line.strip("\n")
    print "---- Using " + search_val + " from file_a to search. ----"
    for b_line in file_b:
        print "Searching file_b using " + b_line.strip("\n")
        if b_line.strip("\n").find(search_val) == 0:
            result += (b_line)
    print "---- Search ended ----"
    # Set the read pointer to the start of the file again
    file_b.seek(0, 0)

    if result:
        # Write the contents of "results" into a file with the name of "search_val"
        with open(search_val + ".txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(result)

file_a.close()
file_b.close()
```

Test Cases:

I am using the test cases in your question:

**file_a.txt**

```
aaaa
bcsg
aacd
gdee
aadw
hwer
```

**file_b.txt**

```
aaaibjkes
aaleoslk
abaaaalkjel
bcsgiweyoieotpwe
csseiolskj
gaelsi asdas
aaaloiersaaageehikjaaa
hwesdaaadf wiibhuehu
bcspwiopiejowih
gdeaes
aaailoiuwegoiglkjaaake
```

The program produces an output file `bcsg.txt` as it is supposed to with `bcsgiweyoieotpwe` inside.

Comment: That's right. My apologies for not being precise in my previous comment. "bcsgiweyoieotpwe" is the only matching string in this sample. But why does the program create zero-byte txt files for strings from file_a.txt without matches in file_b.txt? Thanks again!

Comment: @jigitjigit2 My previous code did that, I just wrote to a new file even when there are no matches. I edited such that it won't do that anymore.

Comment: Fantastic! It works! That's exactly it. Is there any simple way of making the program show the stream of currently read and matched strings? (original file_a and file_b are very long and it would be nice to know where we are in the process. As it is now when I am running the script on these big txt files, I only know that the script is running by watching the use of CPU by Python in system monitor. I cannot see any new text files being created. Perhaps because there is going to be so many of them). Cheers!

Comment: @jigitjigit2 as in `print` out what it is currently doing?

Comment: It works when I try it on shorter versions of my original text files. But when I use the big txt files it does not seem to be doing anything. There are no new txt files in the directory. Is there a limit on the number of lines in text files being processed?

Comment: @jigitjigit2 there shouldn't be a problem reading large files either as I don't store any data as a variable, I only store each line as a variable. Try the edited code with `print` statements.

Comment: @jigitjigit2 if that's all, you can close this post by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help you;

```
file1 = open('file_a.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file_b.txt', 'r')

#get every item in your second file into a list 
mylist = file2.readlines()

# read each line in the first file
while file1.readline():
    searchStr = file1.readline()
    # find this line in your second file
    exists = [s for s in mylist if searchStr in s]
    if (exists):
        # if this line exists in your second file then create a file for it
        fileNew = open(searchStr,'w')
        for line in exists:
            fileNew.write(line)

        fileNew.close()

    file1.close()
```

Comment: Cheers! It doesn't work, though. There seems to be the following error: mylist = file2.readlines()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'deadlines' Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @jigitjigit2 is it a typo or did you put 'deadlines' with a d in your code ? If you paste erolkaya84's code it won't work if you don't open the file first, i'll try to edit his post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f1 = open("a.txt","r").readlines()
f2 = open("b.txt","r").readlines()
file1 = [word.replace("\n","") for word in f1]
file2 = [word.replace("\n","") for word in f2]

data = []
data_dict ={}
for short_word in file1:
    data += ([[short_word,w] for w in file2 if w.startswith(short_word)])

for single_data in data:
    if single_data[0] in data_dict:
        data_dict[single_data[0]].append(single_data[1])
    else:
        data_dict[single_data[0]]=[single_data[1]]

for key,val in data_dict.iteritems():
    open(key+".txt","w").writelines("\n".join(val))
    print(key + ".txt created")
```

Comment: Thank you. The script runs and produces no error messages but it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't create any new txt files. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: In my case aaai.txt and bcsg.txt are created.

Comment: Apologies. It works! It just took a little longer probably due to the large size of my original text files. Thank you very much